# robolectric shadows with final class?

Tags: android, robolectric

Is it possible to create custom Robolectric shadows of final classes?

I am trying to create a shadow of the LocalBluetoothManager in com.android.settings.bluetooth as Robolectric 3.0 does not have it implemented. But I am not able to as it's a final class.

Comment: Can you share some code? Final class should not be problem I think

Comment: I made some changes to the Settings class (that comes with the Android source) and trying to create a shadow of the one the methods that the Settings class creates which is in the same Settings app. However turns out that Robolectric does not allow creating of Shadows of Android classes within the same package as the Class under test. So ultimately I had to resort to creating a shadow that is outside of the Settings package.

Comment: Cool! You can add own answer. It might help others!

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to the Settings class (that comes with the Android source) and trying to create a shadow of the one the methods that the Settings class creates which is in the same Settings app. However turns out that Robolectric does not allow creating of Shadows of Android classes within the same package as the Class under test. So ultimately I had to resort to creating a shadow that is outside of the Settings package.